# About general covariance

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, covariance

\begin{equation} u^{\mu}=\frac{d}{d\tau}x^{\mu} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \partial_{\lambda}(u_{\nu} u^{\nu}) = (\partial_{\lambda}u_{\nu}) u^{\nu} + u_{\nu}(\partial_{\lambda}u^{\nu}) = 0 \end{equation}
and:
\begin{equation} \partial_{\lambda}(u_{\nu} u^{\nu}) = \partial_{\lambda}(u_{\nu} \eta^{\mu\nu}u_{\mu}) =  (\partial_{\lambda}u_{\nu}) u^{\nu} + u^{\mu}(\partial_{\lambda}u_{\mu}) \end{equation}
so that:
\begin{equation} (\partial_{\lambda}u_{\nu}) u^{\nu} = u_{\nu}(\partial_{\lambda}u^{\nu})= 0 
\end{equation}
$u^{\mu}$ is not in general a tensor, it is in SR.
Is the principle of general covariance valid ?
\begin{equation} u_{\nu}(D_{\lambda}u^{\nu})= 0 
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

If $u^\mu$ are the components of the tangent vector to the curve $x^\mu(\tau)$ then the  tanget vector is a *vector*  and hence  a tensor object. If $\tau$ is the arc-length or proper-time parameter of a curve then $
u_\mu u^\mu =+1$ in the $(+,-,-,-)$ metric.  As $u^\mu$ is only defined *on the curve* $x^\mu(\tau)$ you can only define derivatives along the curve.

Along the curve we then have
$$0=(u^\lambda\partial_\lambda) 1=\nabla_u (u^\mu u_\mu)= (\nabla_u u^\mu) u_\mu+ u^\mu(\nabla_u u_\mu)=0,
$$
where $\nabla_u \equiv u^\lambda \nabla_\lambda$.